# POI Currency issues

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to generate excel file using various currencies.

This works fine
public HSSFCellStyle moneyStyle;

```
SSFDataFormat format = excelUtils.wb.createDataFormat();
        moneyStyle = excelUtils.wb.createCellStyle();
        moneyStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("$##,###,###,###,##0"));
```

However if i change the $ to INR (Indian Rupees)  it will not work.

```
public HSSFCellStyle moneyStyle;
SSFDataFormat format = excelUtils.wb.createDataFormat();
        moneyStyle = excelUtils.wb.createCellStyle();
        moneyStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("INR##,###,###,###,##0"));
```

In the Excel spreadsheet the INR does not show up but '$' or 'A$' works just fine

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a valid excel format.  If you want to do this you need to either surround `INR` in double quotes or `\` before each character.

The format you are using would not work if set directly in Excel either.

```
"\\I\\N\\R##,###,###,###,##0"

"\"INR\"##,###,###,###,##0"
```

I believe either should work, though I have only tested directly in Excel.